# Adminlte select2 not working for select box in angularjs

Tags: jquery-select2, adminlte

AdminLte select2 not working means not showing search in select box, i have included css and js file and used like below and also i have included bootstrap related css and js files

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"  ng-options="t.id as t.name for t in tags" ng-model="t_id">

    <option selected="selected">Select Tag</option>
</select>


<script src="bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements   
    $('select2').select2();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work 
$('.select2').select2();

Comment: Can you highlight the differences?

Comment: class selector is missing in code...jquery cannot find element

Comment: Please add such information to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

you may need to load Ajax.googleapis cdn from google. My problem was like as yours.I have faced the problem and solved it. Main problem was select2 doesn't get ajax.googleapis cdn. So, before the jQuery code I have loaded the cdn and it works fine now. You mush notify the version of your cdn. Firstly, the code was

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is looked like the picture below
[image]

> Now after solving the problem the code looks like below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Now it is seen like below
[image]